# Is there a way to speed up Peltier cooling?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, temperature, thermoelectricity

Speed up in sort of like, once you connect the powers, you don't have to wait long for the Peltier element to cool down to desired temperature. Is there a way to fix this, perhaps use two or three Peltier modules or use higher current? Is there any possible ways?